# What operation does Python perform when I pivot a panel dataset with one variable and put month on the Y-axis and years on the X-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot, pivot-table, panel-data

I have a **panel dataset** called `panel_df` with the following columns: `id`, `year`, `month` and a variable `x`.

Then I pass the following line:

`panel_df.pivot_table(values=x, index='month', columns='year')`

The output I obtain is a table with `month` on the y-axis, `year` on the x-axis and each cell is thus a figure uniquely identified by a `year`-`month` pair.

My doubt is: what does Python do when executing the above-mentioned line of code? Is it taking an average of the cross-section i.e. for each `year`-`month` pair taking the average of `x` across all the `id`?

Thanks in advance to everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python version 0.23.4, by default the corresponding parameter *aggfunc* is set to 'mean': 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html
and thus, for each year-month pair, pivot is taking the average of x across all corresponding **observations**.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> panel_df = \
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':[0]*8 + [1]*8,
        'year':[2010]*4 + [2011]*4 + [2010]*4 + [2011]*4,
        'month':[1,1,7,7]*4,
        'x':[i for i in range(16)],
    }
)
>>> panel_df

    id  year  month   x
0    0  2010      1   0
1    0  2010      1   1
2    0  2010      7   2
3    0  2010      7   3
4    0  2011      1   4
5    0  2011      1   5
6    0  2011      7   6
7    0  2011      7   7
8    1  2010      1   8
9    1  2010      1   9
10   1  2010      7  10
11   1  2010      7  11
12   1  2011      1  12
13   1  2011      1  13
14   1  2011      7  14
15   1  2011      7  15
```

and then:

```
>>> panel_df.pivot_table(
    values = 'x',
    index = 'month',
    columns = 'year'
)
year   2010  2011
month            
1       4.5   8.5
7       6.5  10.5
```

is equivalent to:

```
>>> panel_df.pivot_table(
    values = 'x',
    index = 'month',
    columns = 'year',
    aggfunc='mean',
    fill_value=None,
    margins=False
)
year   2010  2011
month            
1       4.5   8.5
7       6.5  10.5
```

You can change default value of parameter *aggfunc*, to 'sum' for example:

```
>>> panel_df.pivot_table(
    values = 'x',
    index = 'month',
    columns = 'year',
    aggfunc='sum',
    fill_value=None,
    margins=False
)
year   2010  2011
month            
1        18    34
7        26    42
```

You might also find useful playing with *margins* value and setting it to True:

```
>>> panel_df.pivot_table(
    values = 'x',
    index = 'month',
    columns = 'year',
    aggfunc='sum',
    fill_value=None,
    margins=True
)

year   2010  2011  All
month                 
1        18    34   52
7        26    42   68
All      44    76  120
```